# Question about mapping x-axis values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am starting to use the matplotlib library to generate simple graphs. In one of my tests something happens to me that does not allow me to obtain the graph that I expect. Coming to the point, I have two value arrays (circle and g) and I would like to join each of their values. The problem comes when I input the x-axis values. I would like only the values of my array g to be on the x axis, but the following happens:

[image]

In my code I have the following:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np

 fig, ax = plt.subplots()

 circle = [0.002,0.013,0.035]
 g = [5,25,50]
 ax.scatter(g[0], circle[0], color = 'g', marker = "o")

 x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
 my_xticks = [0,5,25,50]

 plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
 
 plt.show()
```

Could someone help me fix this?

Comment: If you try to disable `# plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)`, you will understand it better: the ticks on the x-axis do not match the tick names.

Comment: Try changing `x` to the same values to be the same as `my_xticks` and add an extra line `ax.set_xlim(0,50)`. For reference https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Comment: Both solutions are correct but I'm only interested in getting [0,5,25,50] on the x axis

Comment: Use only `plt.xticks(my_xticks)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when calling `plt.xticks()`, you passed `[0, 1, 2, 3]` as the x-tick values, and you passed the tick values you really wanted as the tick *labels*. Instead, pass the tick values you want as the first argument, and omit the second argument. The tick labels will be strings of the tick values by default.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circle = [0.002, 0.013, 0.035]
g = [5, 25, 50]
my_xticks = [0] + g

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(g, circle, color='g', marker='o')
plt.xticks(my_xticks)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot with arbitrary x-ticks]